# How to I run another function after the SetTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is get the question2 function to run upon the settimeout expiring on the questions function.  I threw the settimeout function only on the first 'if' statement to try and test but I will eventually be putting them on all.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

First step is you click the start button, timer starts, and question 1 appears via function questions.  I pull the various answer options and put them in if functions.  If the correct answer is hit correct gets added 1 and everything gets hidden with the image attache to question 1 is displayed.  The issue lies in me wanting to run the question2 function upon the completion of the first question.  Any help would be appreciated.  I have been and am continuing to investigate and would appreciate and feedback possible.

```
$(".Start_Button").click(function() {

    function countdown() {
        timer = 20;
        timerId = setInterval(function() {
        timer--;
        console.log(timer);
        $(".timer").html("Timer: " +timer);
        if(timer == 0) {
            console.log("Time is up");
            alert("Time is up!");
            incorrect ++;
            $("#img1").show();
            $(".list-group").hide();
            $(".Game").hide();
            $(".timer").hide();
            $(".timer").reset();
            }        
        }, 1000);
    }
    countdown();


    $(".Start_Button").hide();
    function questions () {
        $(".list-group").show();
        $(".Game").html(questions[0]);
        $(".list-group-item1").html(answers1[0]);
        $(".list-group-item2").html(answers1[1]);
        $(".list-group-item3").html(answers1[2]);
        $(".list-group-item4").html(answers1[3]);

    if($(".list-group-item4").click(function(){
        setTimeout(function (){
        alert("you got it right!");
        correct ++;
        $("#img1").show();
        $(".list-group").hide();
        $(".Game").hide();
        $(".timer").hide();
        $(".timer").reset();
        question2();
    })
    })); 

  if($(".list-group-item1").click(function(){
       alert("you got it wrong!");
       incorrect ++;
       $("#img1").show();
       $(".list-group").hide();
       $(".Game").hide();
       $(".timer").hide();
       $(".timer").reset();
   }));

   if($(".list-group-item3").click(function(){
        alert("you got it wrong!");
        incorrect ++;
        $("#img1").show();
        $(".list-group").hide();
        $(".Game").hide();
        $(".timer").hide();
        $(".timer").reset();
   }));

  if($(".list-group-item4").click(function(){
        alert("you got it wrong!");
        incorrect ++;
        $("#img1").show();
        $(".list-group").hide();
        $(".Game").hide();
        $(".timer").hide();
        $(".timer").reset();
  }));

}
questions();



function question2() {
$(".list-group").show();
$(".Game").html(questions[1]);
$(".list-group-item1").html(answers2[0]);
$(".list-group-item2").html(answers2[1]);
$(".list-group-item3").html(answers2[2]);
$(".list-group-item4").html(answers2[3]);

if($(".list-group-item2").click(function(){
    alert("you got it right!");
    correct ++;
    $("#img1").show();
    $(".list-group").hide();
    $(".Game").hide();
    $(".timer").hide();
    $(".timer").reset();
})); 

   if($(".list-group-item1").click(function(){
   alert("you got it wrong!");
   incorrect ++;
   $("#img1").show();
   $(".list-group").hide();
   $(".Game").hide();
   $(".timer").hide();
   $(".timer").reset();
  }));

  if($(".list-group-item3").click(function(){
  alert("you got it wrong!");
  incorrect ++;
  $("#img1").show();
  $(".list-group").hide();
  $(".Game").hide();
  $(".timer").hide();
  $(".timer").reset();
  }));

 if($(".list-group-item4").click(function(){
 alert("you got it wrong!");
 incorrect ++;
 $("#img1").show();
 $(".list-group").hide();
 $(".Game").hide();
 $(".timer").hide();
 $(".timer").reset();
 }));    
 }

 question2();

});    
});

 <body>

  <div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-md-12">
    <div class = "timer">
    </div>
    </div>
       </div>


    <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-12">
    <div class = "Game">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

   <div class = "row">
  <div class = "col-md-12">
  <div class = "answers">
  <ul class="list-group">
  <button class="list-group-item1"></button>
  <button class="list-group-item2"></button>
  <button class="list-group-item3"></button>
  <button class="list-group-item4"></button>
   </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>

   <div class = "row">
   </div>

   <div class = "row"></div>
   <div class = "Start_Button">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg">Start</button>
    </div>

   <div class = "Photos">
   <div class = "row">
    <img id = "img1" src = "assets/images/map-of-asia.gif">
    <img id = "img2" src = "assets/images/Flag_of_Canada.svg.png">
    <img id = "img3" src = "assets/images/Antartica.jpg">
    <img id = "img4" src = "assets/images/Peru.jpg">
    <img id = "img5" src = "assets/images/sudan-location-map.jpg">
    <img id = "img6" src = "assets/images/Alaska.jpg">
    <img id = "img7" src = "assets/images/Saudi_Arabia.png">
    <img id = "img8" src = "assets/images/Brazil.jpg">
      </div>
      </div>

      </div>
      </body>
```

Comment: anything "after" the `setTimeout` will run immediately - anything inside the `setTimeout` callback will run when the timeout expires

Comment: Please construct a minimal test case to reproduce the problem rather than dumping ~100 LoC on us. Especially since it's tied intimately to HTML you didn't provide.

Comment: I forgot to add the time but if I put 3000 and where it sits now your saying that everything within the settimeout will run immediately regardless of the time expires? Because the way I have it now none of that is running.

Comment: @JaredSmith I added the HTML below.  As of right now the start button hits and question 1 appears and works i just want to run the next function upon the completion of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I roughly what you mean. Try the script below:

```
$(".Start_Button").click(function() {
     $(".Start_Button").hide();
     questions();
     countdown();
});

function countdown() {
    timer = 20;
    timerId = setInterval(function() {
    timer--;
    console.log(timer);
    $(".timer").html("Timer: " +timer);
    if(timer == 0) {
        console.log("Time is up");
        alert("Time is up!");
        incorrect ++;
        $("#img1").show();
        $(".list-group").hide();
        $(".Game").hide();
        $(".timer").hide();
        $(".timer").reset();

        //call question2 here
        question2();
        countdown(); //reset timer again
        }        
    }, 1000);
}

function questions () {
    $(".list-group").show();
    $(".Game").html(questions[0]);
    $(".list-group-item1").html(answers1[0]);
    $(".list-group-item2").html(answers1[1]);
    $(".list-group-item3").html(answers1[2]);
    $(".list-group-item4").html(answers1[3]);

    $(".list-group-item4").click(function(){
        setTimeout(function (){
        alert("you got it right!");
        correct ++;
        $("#img1").show();
        $(".list-group").hide();
        $(".Game").hide();
        $(".timer").hide();
        $(".timer").reset();
        question2();
    });

    $(".list-group-item1").click(function(){
       alert("you got it wrong!");
       incorrect ++;
       $("#img1").show();
       $(".list-group").hide();
       $(".Game").hide();
       $(".timer").hide();
       $(".timer").reset();
   });

   $(".list-group-item3").click(function(){
        alert("you got it wrong!");
        incorrect ++;
        $("#img1").show();
        $(".list-group").hide();
        $(".Game").hide();
        $(".timer").hide();
        $(".timer").reset();
   });

   $(".list-group-item4").click(function(){
        alert("you got it wrong!");
        incorrect ++;
        $("#img1").show();
        $(".list-group").hide();
        $(".Game").hide();
        $(".timer").hide();
        $(".timer").reset();
  });
}


function question2() {

    $(".list-group").show();
    $(".Game").html(questions[1]);
    $(".list-group-item1").html(answers2[0]);
    $(".list-group-item2").html(answers2[1]);
    $(".list-group-item3").html(answers2[2]);
    $(".list-group-item4").html(answers2[3]);

    $(".list-group-item2").click(function(){
        alert("you got it right!");
        correct ++;
        $("#img1").show();
        $(".list-group").hide();
        $(".Game").hide();
        $(".timer").hide();
        $(".timer").reset();
    }); 

      $(".list-group-item1").click(function(){
       alert("you got it wrong!");
       incorrect ++;
       $("#img1").show();
       $(".list-group").hide();
       $(".Game").hide();
       $(".timer").hide();
       $(".timer").reset();
      });

      $(".list-group-item3").click(function(){
      alert("you got it wrong!");
      incorrect ++;
      $("#img1").show();
      $(".list-group").hide();
      $(".Game").hide();
      $(".timer").hide();
      $(".timer").reset();
      });

     $(".list-group-item4").click(function(){
     alert("you got it wrong!");
     incorrect ++;
     $("#img1").show();
     $(".list-group").hide();
     $(".Game").hide();
     $(".timer").hide();
     $(".timer").reset();
     });    

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue might lie in where you are calling your function for question2 within your questions() function.

Try taking the `question2()` function out of the setTimeOut() callback for a complete answer, and after you write your event handlers for the questions() function, write a ternary operator that checks to see your the counter for `correct` was incremented by 1. If it was incremented (i.e. `correct++`), then render question2()

Comment: So something like this at the end?        
   if(correct === 1 || incorrect === 1) {
        question2();
    }

Comment: Yes basically and put that LOC after all your conditionals in the questions() function. I think you could also have created a second variable that’s equal to the original count  , that way if you implement more than one question later on it’ll be easier to reuse that logic

Answer (score 0):

In simpler way it can be done like this:

```
function test1() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        test2();
    }, 3000)
}
test1();
function test2() {
    console.log(5)
}
```